# Convex Function of Two Vectors

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^M\times\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a mapping such that for $\mathbf{Y}\in\mathbb{R}^N$ constant, $f(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y})$ is a convex function of $\mathbf{X}$  and for $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^M$ constant, $f(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y})$ is a convex function of $\mathbf{Y}$. If $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are merged into a single vector, how about the convexity of $f$ in that vector? Will it be definitely convex or nothing it's impossible to assert? Outline of a proof will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you go about merging X and Y? Some sort of a direct product?

Comment: @Anurag, no. Just forming a new vector joining X and Y. For example, if X=(X_1, X_2, X_3) and Y=(Y_1, Y_2) then f can be considered as a function of the vector Z=(X_1, X_2, X_3, Y_1, Y_2). Will it be a convex function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x,y)=xy$

$$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2,ty_1+(1-t)y_2)-tf(x_1,y_1)-(1-t)f(x_2y_2)=t(1-t)[-x_1y_1-x_2y_2+x_2y_1+x_1y_2]=-t(1-t)(y_1-y_2)(x_1-x_2)$$

If $x_1>x_2$ and $y_1<y_2$ then this is positive and $f$ is not convex.